# Why is Papadopoulos such a common surname in Greece?

Tags: greek, names

*[Papadopoulos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papadopoulos)* is the most common Greek surname. It means "son of a priest". The female version is *Papadopoulou*.

I wonder why.

As far as I know, priests don't marry and are celibate, meaning they can't father a child. So, how did this become a common surname?

Does the expression "son of a priest" carry another meaning that I'm missing?

Comment: Priests of the Eastern Church are not bound to the same restrictions of celibacy as Roman Catholic priests - ie, they can be married. Also, priestly celibacy was not an original requirement of the Church anyway, but came later.

Comment: @Mark Beadles You have it backward.  Priests cannot marry.  Married men can be ordained.  The order (no pun intended) matters.

Comment: @CMonsour I carefully did not specify an order, simply stated that "priests can be married". I realize now that the way I phrased it was ambiguous, though. (Technically it's possible for an RC priest to be a married man as well but that's exceedingly rare and involves conversion after being ordained in another Church...)

Comment: @Mark Beadles It's also not true that it's that rare for married men to be RC priests.  You are confusing RC with "Latin Rite RC".

Comment: @CMonsour I think it _is_ rare; the other particular churches have far fewer priests.

Comment: @CMonsour: There are many *Catholic* Christian denominations, including Anglicans/Episcopalians and all the Orthodox denominations. However only those recognizing the authority of  the *Bishop of Rome* as supreme authority are *Roman Catholics*. Anglican priests are allowed to marry, after ordination as well as before.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens You seem to be unaware of the existence of Roman Catholics (i.e., they recognize the authority of the bishop of Rome) who are not Latin Rite (i.e., they do not use the Western Liturgy and have a separate clerical hierarchy subordinate to the pope).  These are collectively Eastern Rite Roman Catholics, for example including the Maronites and including the Ukrainian Greek Catholics.  And they most certainly allow the ordination of married men to the priesthood.

Comment: @AaronBrick I don't think you should call something rare if it is widespread in large communities, e.g., Lebanon or Ukraine.  Certainly it's not the sort of rarity that Mark Beadles was mistakenly implying.

Comment: @CMonsour: I was indeed unaware. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Yes, my mistake was to use the term "RC" instead of "Latin Rite Roman Catholic Church" or "Latin Church", my bad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Orthodox Church parish priests are virtually always married. Monks and higher clergy (Bishops etc.) are celibate.

Comment: I believe they are only allowed to marry before taking their clerical vows. Yes, many are married. I think "virtually all" deserves a citation. Of course, the question is about the past.

Comment: @AaronBrick. Yes, they need to marry before ordination.